# Pandas, drop duplicate Name Rows, if the name is more than 20 characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame called df:

```
Name     State
Down     NY
Down     NY
Down     NY
Next In  NJ
Next In  NJ
Next In  NJ
```

I want to be able to drop duplicates rows based on Name only if the name is more than 5 characters long.
Is this possible with drop_duplicates?

Comment: you can try `df = df[df['Name'].str.len()<=5]`

Comment: @Epsi95 this is not op's asnwer, op wants drop duplicated for row str.len() > 5 –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find rows that `str.len () > 5` and `drop_duplicated` these row then append with other rows.
Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Down','Down','Down','Next In','Next In','Next In'],
    'State': ['NY','NY','NY','NY','NY','NY']
})

mask = (df['Name'].str.len() > 5)
df[mask].drop_duplicates().append(df[~mask]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
    Name    State
0   Down    NY
1   Down    NY
2   Down    NY
3   Next In NY
```

Comment: `df[mask].drop_duplicates().append(df[~mask]).sort_index()`

Answer (score 1):

You can `drop_duplicates()` only on rows where Name has a length of more than 5, and `pd.cocnat()` it with the other part of the DataFrame:

```
pd.concat([df[df.Name.str.len()<=5],df[df.Name.str.len()>5].drop_duplicates()],axis=0)

      Name State
0     Down    NY
1     Down    NY
2     Down    NY
3  Next In    NJ
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also drop that rows where value in column "Name" exists in more than one row and the len of Name is greater than 5 using function 'drop' from data frame. Axis = 0 means that we will drop rows, inplace= True means we will work on variable df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Down', 'Down', 'Down', 'Next In', 'Next In', 'Next 
In'], 'State':['NY', 'NJ', 'NY', 'NY', 'NJ', 'NJ']})

#Iterate over all rows
for ind in df.index:
   #checks if name is greater than 5 and checks number of occurences of the name in whole dataframe
    if (len(df.iloc[ind]["Name"])>5 and df.value_counts(subset=['Name'])[df.iloc[ind]["Name"]]>1):
        df.drop(ind, axis=0, inplace=True)
```